# log4net custom appender dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, log4net

I'm going to implement a log4net custom appender. 
My appender work fine but during refactory i want isolate the responsability, so i need to inject one interface.
I write some code so you can understand

```
namespace WebServiceLogger.Interfaces
{
    public interface IClientService
    {
        void SendLog(string logToSend);
    }
}
```

This is my Appender that now send log by mail, but 
tomorrow i want use the same appender for send log to a web service.

```
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Core;
using WebServiceLogger.Interfaces;

namespace WebServiceLogger
{
    public class WebServiceLogAppender : AppenderSkeleton
    {
        private IClientService _clientService;

        //Url property is declared with tag in my log4net.config tag
        public string Url { get; set; }     
        public WebServiceLogAppender()
        {
            InitializeClientService(); 
        }

        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            var log = RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent);
            _clientService.SendLog(log);
        }

        private void InitializeClientService()
        {
            var smtpClientFactory = new SmtpClientFactory();
            var mailMessageFactory = new MailMessageFactory();
            _clientService = new EmailClientService(smtpClientFactory,mailMessageFactory)
        }
    }
}
```

And one class that implement IClientService

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using WebServiceLogger.Interfaces;

namespace WebServiceLogger
{
    public class EmailClientService : IClientService
    {
        private readonly SmtpClient _smtpClient;
        private readonly IMailMessageFactory _mailMessageFactory;

        public EmailClientService(ISmtpClientFactory smtpClientFactory, IMailMessageFactory mailMessageFactory)
        {
            _smtpClient = smtpClientFactory.Create("username", "password");
            _mailMessageFactory = mailMessageFactory;
        }

        public void SendLog(string logToSend)
        {
            var message = _mailMessageFactory.CreateMailMessage(logToSend);
            _smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want cable the webservice inside this class but i have only a parameterless constructor.

The answer is , can i specify the object of one class that implement the IClientService interface in log4net.config ?

Comment: Sorry i don't need of Url property

Comment: why don't u just write a different appender? that is what the appenders were made for

Comment: Because I have different web service !

Comment: yeah,so write an email logger and a webservicelogger ?!which is neater anyway a class called WebServiceLogger that send eamail is imho bad design

Comment: The question was : how to implement an appender for different web service that expose different contracts ? ... i think that, in this case, generics implementation don't match the SOLID principle ...

Answer (score 3):

Because log4net creates the appenders itself, it isn't possible to use constructor or property injection, and you cannot specify a class in the config: you could if you really wanted to just specify the name of the class implementing `IClientService` in the config and create it at runtime, but that's not really advisable.

If your intention is to reduce code duplication, then creating a base class for your custom logger will do that: then you can mix and match the appenders in your config file.

```
public abstract class BaseWebServiceLogAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    protected IClientService _clientService;

    //Url property is declared with tag in my log4net.config tag
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public BaseWebServiceLogAppender()
    {
        InitializeClientService();
    }

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        var log = RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent);
        _clientService.SendLog(log);
    }

    protected abstract void InitializeClientService();
}

public class EmailWebServiceLogAppender : BaseWebServiceLogAppender
{
    protected override void InitializeClientService()
    {
        var smtpClientFactory = new SmtpClientFactory();
        var mailMessageFactory = new MailMessageFactory();
        _clientService = new EmailClientService(smtpClientFactory,mailMessageFactory)
    }
}

public class SmsWebServiceLogAppender : BaseWebServiceLogAppender
{
    protected override void InitializeClientService()
    {
        _clientService = new SmSClientService(…);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which container you are using. In my case, I am using Unity and was able to run the appender instance through the container after its creation:

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("My Logger");
IAppender[] appenders = logger.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders();
foreach (IAppender appender in appenders)
{
    container.BuildUp(appender.GetType(), appender);
}

container.RegisterInstance(logger);
```

`BuildUp()` method will populate the injection property in the appender class:

```
public class LogDatabaseSaverAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    [Dependency]
    public IContextCreator ContextCreator { get; set; }

    ...
}
```