# Inject Dependency in Derived Appender from AppenderSkeleton

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq, log4net-appender

I am implementing Log4net in our application and for logging I am implementing **AppenderSkeleton**.

Since log4net resolves its appender using configuration setting I am not able to specify my custom service as a dependency injected using either constructor or property.

The reason I want to do so is because I want my appender to be unit tested using MOQ framework.

Following is a code sample of what I want to achieve.

```
public class LoggingAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    private ICustomService service;
    public LoggingAppender(ICustomService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
    protected override void Append(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        service.Method("Data From loggingEvent");
    }
}
```

I also found the following answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791520/log4net-custom-appender-dependency). But it doesn't serve the purpose for me.

Is there any solution to this issue or should we follow any other approach in order to unit test it?

Comment: See the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634472/using-ioc-in-a-custom-log4net-appender

Comment: I guess since constructor injection is not available property injection would be a potential solution as suggested by the link provided by @IgorGnedysh.

Comment: Let me check how it fits with Windsor Castle DI container.

Comment: @Nkosi cant be done using Windsor Castle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851940/windsor-castle-injecting-properties-of-constructed-object

Comment: @AshutoshSingh then all you have left is to redesign the class to use an abstract factory method that uses service locator anti-pattern or pure DI https://stackoverflow.com/a/30807022/5233410

Comment: @IgorGnedysh any suggestion?

Comment: @Nkosi another link suggest that yes it can be done but the above link is latest compared to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447193/resolving-classes-without-registering-them-using-castle-windsor

Answer (score 0):

@AshutoshSingh in that case I would suggest to add appender in runtime. see [How to add log4net appender in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833362/how-to-add-log4net-appender-in-runtime) (note that there's a bunch of levels where you could register appender, not only that one).

Also you may add factory regisration for ILogger which will add appender upon resolving, as an option (see [Castle Windsor: How do I register a factory method, when the underlying type isn't accessible to my assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858668/castle-windsor-how-do-i-register-a-factory-method-when-the-underlying-type-isn)).

In any case by following that references you will have some info you could play with.

PS: do not have enough of reputation to reply in original thread :-) so will post answer here :-)